# How RF Choke doubles Vcc at collector in BJT Power Amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, inductor, state-space, power-amplifier

I'm trying to analyze a class A RF power amplifier as represented in the picture.  The main thing I'm trying to understand is how the collector voltage can go to 2x Vcc as according to this page.   [The ABC’s of PA’s.](http://rfic.eecs.berkeley.edu/ee242/pdf/Module_6_2_PA_Classes.pdf)   According to the author because VL=L(di/dt) Vce can swing from 0 to 2xVcc.
Of course I understand that the voltage across the inductor is V_L = L(di/dt), but what i don't understand is what constrains V_L = L(di/dt) to be between 0V and |Vcc|?  I would expect that V_L = L(di/dt) could take any arbitrary value depending on the collector current swing, Ic.[image: Class A PA] 
I though I might be able to understand by using something like state space analysis or systems of simultaneous linear DEs using the model below. [image: Circuit PA]
The equations I'm coming up with don't seem that helpful though.
[image]

[image]
For one thing I'm not sure how to define Ic in a way that would be useful.

If anyone could give me any suggestions I would really appreciate it. If there's a quick explanation of V_L and why  0V < L(di/dt) < |Vcc| it would be great.   I'd also like to be able to go back and analyze this to understand it better though. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you also have a biasing network?

Comment: *"what i don't understand is what constrains V_L = L(di/dt) to be between 0V and |Vcc|?"* - it isn't constrained within these limits. You seem to be contradicting yourself.

Comment: Modern_Communication_Circuits_Smith_1ed.pdf pag,455

Comment: Here a relevant video https://youtu.be/GtFnkXar5JU?t=897

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, best to look at the problem as having 2 parts, DC and RF. Now if L is perfect then if there is any difference in the DC voltage between the collector and the supply then there will be a large DC current through the inductor.  Therefore av(Vc) = Vcc. (where av() is average over a cycle). Since we're talking about sine waves, and since the transistor's collector can't drop below 0, you get that Vc must have an amplitude of Vcc, ie it swings from 0 to 2Vcc so that it's average is Vcc.

Comment: I think you have missed the equation

Comment: yes, I tried to use <> to denote the average, that didn't format correctly in Stackexchange.  Now fixed to use av().